# Ruby Gems won't run

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I'm trying to run different gems on Raspbian and they won't work.  I tried on two gems: Jekyll and Lolcat.

I've installed both gems:

```
pi@moon ~ $ sudo gem install lolcat
Successfully installed lolcat-42.0.99
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for lolcat-42.0.99...
Installing RDoc documentation for lolcat-42.0.99...

pi@moon ~ $ sudo gem install jekyll
Successfully installed jekyll-1.4.3
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for jekyll-1.4.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for jekyll-1.4.3...
```

These are the errors I receive.

```
pi@moon ~ $ lolcat --help
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find lolcat (>= 0)   
amongst [bundler-1.5.3, bundler-unload-1.0.2, executable-hooks-1.3.1, gem-wrappers-1.2.4, rubygems-bundler-1.4.2, rvm-1.11.3.9] (Gem::LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
from /usr/local/bin/lolcat:22:in `<main>'

pi@moon ~ $ jekyll
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find jekyll (>= 0) 
amongst [bundler-1.5.3, bundler-unload-1.0.2, executable-hooks-1.3.1, gem-wrappers-1.2.4, rubygems-bundler-1.4.2, rvm-1.11.3.9] (Gem::LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:22:in `<main>'
```

I was advised to re-install ruby using RVM. I did, and when I run `rvm list` to see my ruby versions, I get the following:

```
pi@moon ~ $ rvm list

rvm rubies

=> ruby-1.9.1-p431 [ armv6l ]
 * ruby-2.1.0 [ armv6l ]
```

I tried running the gems on both versions (1.9.1 & 2.1.0) but receive the same errors.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hint - you haven't installed either of those gems.

Comment: @mcfinnigan Would have been rather hilarious of that was true, but I believe I did. `sudo gem install jekyll` and `sudo gem install lolcat`. I'll put the results of running those two commands in the post.

Comment: issue the command `gem list` after `rvm use ruby-2.1.0` to verify.

Comment: also, further to your edit above, sudo installs the gems as root, which is a) likely why they're not accessible as a normal user and b) bad security practice.

Comment: @mcfinnigan It's more embarrassing than hilarious. You're right, the gems don't show. But I have installed them, on root also. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use sudo to install gems under rvm.

Comment: you installed them as root.  Don't do this.  Install them as the user who needs to be able to run the ruby processes.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to undo my root installation? Is it `sudo gem uninstall`?

Comment: @mcfinnigan Please write this is an answer so I can mark this as solved :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Several things were wrong here:

Firstly, the gems had been installed as root, which meant that their codebase (and any shell scripts or binary commands their installation generated) were root's, not the current users.  This was the cause of OP's original failure - namely, the executable scripts could not resolve the gems since they were installed under a different user's rvm environment.

Secondly, even had the gems commands been accessible this could have created all sorts of security problems, given that the files belonged to root.  Potentially, if these gems had contained badly-behaved code (or malicious code) embedded within them, a privilege escalation attack might have been possible against the system running the ruby process.

Basically, the TL;DR is that you should always install the gems using the credentials of the user who needs to run the ruby process that requires the gems, and this user should never be `root` or have superuser rights to the system or filesystem.